# How to import excel file in attendance module in odoo 12 community?

Tags: excel, module, odoo-12, data-import, time-and-attendance

I'm trying to import an excel file in attendance module in odoo 12 community, but I cannot find the import button anywhere after going to Attendance -> Manage Attendance > Attendances? Even though I installed the base import module already.

Please help!

Thank you and Best Regards,

Comment: Please check if Import option available in other modules?

Comment: Hi Younis, I already checked it. And it not available in other modules too! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Import button is only visible in Tree view. Are you trying to import in Tree view or form view?

Comment: Hi Younis, I have an excel form file and I need to import it to Odoo server after I completed to install Odoo 12. As you said that, the import button is only visible in Tree view. So the Odoo server will show the form view mode by default, right? So, how to change to the Tree view mode? like this https://ibb.co/brW0hLf .

Comment: Hi Younis, I'm a new comer of Odoo. Please help me to explain this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Import button is only visible in Tree view.
To activate Tree View at your right hand side below search bar there are some icons representing different views of data[image]

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your support. There are something wrong with the installation of Odoo in virtual environment that I cannot see the Import button. But when I installed the Odoo with the real environment. The Import button visible clearly now in Tree View mode! I don't know why? But it took me a lot of time.